# Join data imported in different variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I've imported data from Excel into several variables and I would like to join all data in one "big" variable. I seem to have a problem when one variable contains numerical data...

`a = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
b = {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}};
c = {{z1, z2, z3}, {t1, t2, t3}};
d = {5};
r = Join[a, b, Transpose[c], d]`

Result:

> {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}, {z1, 
>     t1}, {z2, t2}, {z3, t3}, 5}

But if `d = 5` , `Join[]` is not functioning anymore:

> Join::normal1: Expression {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}} at position 1 is expected to have nonatomic subexpression at level 5. >>

Result:

> Join[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, 
>      v3}}, {{z1, t1}, {z2, t2}, {z3, t3}}, 5]

What is wrong? And how I can avoid it, considering that I have no influence on  `d = 5`, as it is imported like this...

Comment: @Karsten 7. Yes, but this will "disaggregate" the initial pairs of values: `{x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3, z1, t1, z2, t2, z3, t3}`

Comment: @Karsten 7. It's ok now, my mistake, sorry. Sometimes in Mathematica you forget a bracket or something and this is not causing any error message, but you don't get the wished result also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your `r` with

```
r = Join[{a}, {b}, {Transpose[c]}, {d}] ~Flatten~ 1
```

With this definition the output is

> `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {u1, v1}, {u2, v2}, {u3, v3}, {z1, t1}, 
>   {z2, t2}, {z3, t3}, 5}`

both for `d = {5};` and `d = 5;`.
By adding the extra `{}` you ensure that each parameter of `Join` is a `List`. These extra `{}` are than remove by `Flatten` with second parameter `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Join is a peculiar function. It interprets its last argument, if and only if that argument is an integer, as a level specification. That is why

```
Join[a, b, Transpose[c], d]
```

complains about level 5 when `d = 5`. Further, all the arguments except other than that optional last integer must have the same head. So

Join[a, d, b, Transpose[c]]

won't work either because `d` has different head that the other arguments. In this case `Join` returns unevaluated; no error message is issued.

What this means to you is that you must wrap `d` in `List` before it is passed to `Join`. Karsten 7 has shown one way to do that. Here is another.

```
 Join @@ ({a, b, Transpose[c], d} /. x_?NumericQ -> {x})
```